# multiple function on ng-click angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click, ng-hide, angularjs-ng-show

I'm new to AngularJs and learning now, in my current assignment I need to achieve multiple things on ng-click.

1. To hide and show some DOM elements based on the ng-click
2. Change the background of the element where the ng-click is applied on, I'm trying to acheive this using a directive.

Mark-up:

```
    <div class="catFilter f6" ng-click="showSubCat = !showSubCat;toggleDropDown()">
        Choose A Genre
    </div>

    <div class="inactive" ng-show="showSubCat" ng-click="hideSubCat = !hideSubCat" ng-hide="!hideSubCat">
    </div>
    <div class="cat-drop-menu-list" ng-show="showSubCat" ng-hide="!hideSubCat">
    </div>
```

angular directive

```
retailApp.directive('toggleDropDown', function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $scope.clickingCallback = function() {
        element.css({'background':'url("../images/down-arrow.png") no-repeat 225px 12px;'});
    };
    element.bind('click', $scope.clickingCallback);
}
});
```

Issues:

I'm not able to see the directive being applied, i.e., when I click on choose a genre, it is hiding and showing the other two divs, but not changing the back ground.

Comment: Please provide  your code on http://jsfiddle.net/? It is easy to fix your assignment?

Comment: do you mean `scope` instead of `$scope?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a couple ways, with bindings or directives:

http://jsfiddle.net/abjeex75/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.show_sub_cat = false;

    $scope.show = function () {
        $scope.show_sub_cat = true;
    }

    $scope.hide = function () {
        $scope.show_sub_cat = false;
    }
});

app.directive('toggleBg', function () {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    }

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('click', function () {
            element.toggleClass('red');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: one quick question, what do I need to do if I want to hide the button 2 and button 3, if I click on the button 1 again.

Comment: never mind. I figured it out. Once again thanks for the timely help.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth please do accept the answer if that solved your problem, upvote would be added bonus :)

Comment: @HarishR - how can I do that, could you please direct me. I've not used this forum much before. I can to that If I know how to do that.

Comment: just click on the arrow that you see on left-top besides the answer to accept the answer, similarly there are up and down arrows, just click on up arrow to upvote